# How to add custom option in the table properties ckeditor 5 in drupal 9

Tags: drupal-9, ckeditor5-plugin

I have a site based on drupal 9 and I am trying to add a new option like (Responsive: Yes/No) in the properties of the ckeditor 5 table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They already fixed it soon to release it in Drupal 10+

I already tried the patch for drupal 9 its also working but its to bugy lets wait until the final release

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3324225